# In VIM, how do I write all (:wa), but only for non-hidden buffers?

Tags: vim

Sometimes I switch Git branches without closing VIM buffers for files that are unique to the current branch. Those buffers will be hidden, and I'll open new buffers in splits and start making changes for the new branch. Rather than `:w` individually on those new buffers, I'd like to `:wa`, but that writes to all buffers, including the old ones that are now hidden.

This is frustrating because it writes those old buffers to new files since they don't exist, dirtying my branch.

How do I `:wa`, but only for the non-hidden buffers that are actively open in my splits?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since the buffers you want to write are all displayed in windows you can:

```
:windo w
```

or the slightly smarter:

```
:windo update
```

See `:help :windo` and `:help :update`.

Comment: Excellent. Of course I'd over engineer a solution, wouldn't I? I'm not deleting it though, to have something to laugh at :) The only difference I can spot is that `:windo` operates on the current tab only, so technically not all the active buffers like the manually selected way I used. This may or may not be desirable, if one uses tabs.

Answer (score 3):

There is no native command to do that, but creating your own
is not very difficult. Buffers  have attributes, and you are
looking  for the  ones considered  *active*, which  have the
`hidden` flag set to false.

You  can get  a list  of buffers  with `getbufinfo()`.  This
functions returns an array of dictionaries containing buffer
information. Then  it is  a matter  of iterating  over these
entries  and  if it  does  not  represent a  hidden  buffer,
perform the write (or `:update`).

As far as I know there is no native way to perform a command
in a different  buffer without switching to it.  We are thus
forced to switch to a different buffer to perform a command.
This would mess up your current buffer, but can be solved by
saving it before looping and restoring later.

The  following  function  does that,  and  the  accompanying
custom command `:Wa` just calls it.

```
function! WriteActiveBuffers()
  " Save current buffer number
  let current = bufnr('%')
  for buffer in getbufinfo({'buflisted':1})
    if !buffer["hidden"]
      " Found an active buffer
      " Switch to it
      execute 'buffer' buffer["bufnr"]
      " Write if modified
      update
    endif
  endfor
  " Restore current buffer
  execute 'buffer' current
endfunction

command! Wa call WriteActiveBuffers()
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmm. Slightly altering from the literal question and taking the use case into account, I'd just advise you to use:

```
autocmd BufEnter * setlocal bufhidden=delete
```

in your .vimrc. Maybe restrict * a bit, and then just use pure `:wa` as you won't have any hidden buffers anymore. :| That might work.